# Org latex preview untoggle when toggling

Tags: org-mode, preview-latex

when I have latex in a section, and press `C-c C-x C-l` it preview all LaTeX fragments in the section, and when I jump to another section and toggle latex preview fragment for that section, it untoggle the latex preview of the other section.

By section I mean an outline, or source code.

For example I have some LaTeX in an outline and some in a source code (because I am writing a lesson), and when I toggle the LaTeX in the source code, it untogle the LaTeX of the outline.

How can I prevent that ?

Is there a way to have a binding to preview all the LaTeX of a document, even if it's already previewed ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `org-preview-latex-fragment` documentation, if you use a double prefix, it'll display all fragments in the buffer:

> It is bound to C-c C-x C-l.
>
> (org-preview-latex-fragment &optional SUBTREE)
>
> Preview the LaTeX fragment at point, or all locally or globally. If
>   the cursor is in a LaTeX fragment, create the image and overlay it
>   over the source code.  If there is no fragment at point, display all
>   fragments in the current text, from one headline to the next.  With
>   prefix SUBTREE, display all fragments in the current subtree.  **With a
>   double prefix arg C-u C-u, or when the cursor is before the first
>   headline, display all fragments in the buffer.** The images can be
>   removed again with M-x org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c.

Comment: Thank you that solve the problem !
Is there a way I can bind it to an easier sequence ?

Comment: Something like `(global-set-key (kbd "<f11>") (lambda () (interactive) (org-preview-latex-fragment 16)))` should do the trick. Note that the double `C-u` produces an argument of 16 to the function.

Comment: `org-preview-latex-fragment` since version 9.3 you should use `org-latex-preview`

Comment: @Juancho I love you